# Has anyone figured out how to use same username with different passwords (Windows)

Tags: windows, authentication

Tried Googling, tried net use, and anything I could, with no results.

I have a PC with users, and I have a network server with shared folders. For some users the usernames of the share and local account match, but the passwords are different (a good security practice).

Unfortunately, Windows doesn't want to remap the drives on login, and asks for credentials when I try to connect.

If I enter the password, the connection succeeds, but it still fails on next login, even if I have checked the "remember" checkbox.

On PC: usera@machinea pass1
On NAS: usera@nas pass2

`net use z: \\nasip\usera /user:nasip\usera pass2 /persistent:yes`

Credential store seems to have the user credentials stored... But the mapping fails all the time.

Comment: Realistically, I think the security benefits of using two different passwords are negated by the practice of getting Windows to remember the second password for you.  So you may as well just use the same password - although I'm not certain this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 6):

You should use Active Directory, that way authorization and authentication are all handled transparently by Kerberos.

Answer (score 3):

The PC is standalone, so AD is not a solution in my case.

After doing more random things, I finally found a solution. If I open the credential manager manually, and enter a server credentials, IP/username/password, then I can later connect to the server without prompt and mapping succeeds afterwards.

Any other way net use/remember password/map from GUI with password prompt are spectacular failures.

So, if you have same username, but different passwords on different PCs, use credential manager to create a credential first, then do the mapping. This is the only way that works.